# mysql - Not able to create table with specific name pattern

Tags: mysql, database

I tried too many combinations with adding and removing characters from table name and i came to conclusion that if table name contains specific sequence like one numeric character after and before 'e' then mysql not able to generate table.

```
create table 28e78f70_4461_4950_8893_ad848dee55f1_20180517111601410 (id BIGINT) ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Above query throws error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '28e78f70 (id BIGINT) ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT' at line 1
```

but it works if i add any char before table name like 'e28e78f70'

```
create table e28e78f70 (id BIGINT) ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

above query get executed successfully.

is there any specific reason for this misbehave ?

Comment: The first table does not create because the table names start with an integer, I have posted an answer below, you can use that special quote to create table starting with a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL as below to create the table that start with number:

```
create table `28e78f70` (id BIGINT) ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: not working with :  create table '28e78f70_4461_4950_8893_ad848dee55f1_20180517111601410' (id BIGINT) ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT

Comment: the quote that I mention in my answer is "back quote" not "single quote". "back quote" is associated with key "~". I mean you have to use " ` " not " ' "

Comment: There is three quote on keyword: 1. Single quote -- ' --, 2. Double quote -- " --, 3. Back quote -- ` --. Hope you clear

Comment: Copy my create statement syntax and just update your table_name, and try it will work for u